# wpf textbox: trouble with default sizing and UI automation behaviour

Tags: wpf, textbox, treeview, ui-automation

I have a wpf `TreeView` with customized Items. 
Each node is a wpf Border with a wpf expander inside. The expander contains the child items of the node, and so on. So every `TreeViewNode` has its items inside.

`TreeViewItem`: UI Representation:

```
the outer element: a wpf Border (the node): 

/-----------------\
|                 |
| title(textbox)  |
|                 |
|  \/Expander     |
|  |        |     |
|  | child  |     |
|  | items  |     |
|  ----------     |
|                 |
\-----------------/
```

The `Viewmodel` for the `TreeViewItem` has an `ObservableCollection` of further `TreeviewItem`s.

If I add items using `ObservableCollection<Item>.Add(..)`,
the `TreeviewItem` View shows the node with the new item: it enlarges the wpf `Border` and shows the new item inside the wpf `Expander`.

If I remove `Items` using `ObservableCollectionyItem>.Remove(..)`,  The `Border` shrinks again and shows an empty expander.

This is the behavior that I want to keep!

Problem: I used for the `TextBox`:

```
DockPanel.Dock = "Top"
```

to fit to the `Border` width. This stretches the `TextBox` to fit the new border width.
When I remove a child Item, the border won't get reduced in width, because the `TextBox` 
is now larger. But I want the `TextBox`to be independant from the outer border.

The `TextBox` should resize to the available space, when child items are added,
but should not influence the border from snapping back to a smaller size, when child items are removed.There should be no dependency from the `TextBox` width to any Layout elements.
How to achieve this?

example: If I use `DockPanel.Dock="Left"` for the textbox,
it will not grow (*not* good), but the border will snap back to its former size (*good*), when removing elements.

How can I make the width of the textbox *not* be relevant for the wpf automatic UI sizing ? By the way, I don't want to size the treeviewitems from code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very useful hint here:

stackoverflow.com/questions/6338315/allow-wpf-grid-cell-content-to-expand-outside-of-the-grid-cell

If you put the textbox inside a canvas, it won't influence the outer border width!